# Round number wrong

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-2007, precision

A friend of mine discovered a really weird thing in MS Excel. Excel rounds down some specific numbers the wrong way, actually it rounds down a number that shouldn't need rounding.

As far as I have tested, it happens in most versions of MS Excel 2007+

Eg. the number `10358.165790` will be rounded down to `10358.1657899999`.

Apparently it only happens in this interval: `8192.165790 - 65535.165790`.

It is really weird - it doesn't happen with eg. `.165890` or `.165690`, only with `.165790`.

Do any of you know why this happens and why it only accounts to certain numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Excel uses an IEEE754 64 bit double precision floating point type to represent numeric data; with some clever formatting and roundup tricks to get sums like 1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3 correct.

What you are observing is a natural consequence of that numeric scheme only being accurate to 15 significant figures. Unless the number happens to be a dyadic rational, in which case it can be stored exactly, the closest representable number is chosen to the one you actually want. This may be below or above a rounding cutoff.

It will occur in other ranges other than the one you cite too.

Comment: Thank you for explaining :-)